# set sum of dynamic keys within an object inside an array of object

Tags: javascript

I have one array of object which looks something like this:-

```
const myObjArr = [
        {
            "channelName": "AFM",
            "21-Apr-2022": 2,
            "22-Apr-2022": 2,
            "27-Apr-2022": 1,
            "29-Apr-2022": 3,
            "19-Apr-2022": 1
        },
        {
            "channelName": "Organic Others",
            "6-Apr-2022": 6,
            "27-Apr-2022": 4,
            "7-Apr-2022": 3,
            "21-Apr-2022": 1,
            "8-Apr-2022": 1
        },
        {
            "channelName": "website",
            "27-Apr-2022": 1
        }
    ]
```

now I want to add one more key, which is named as  total in each object of this array which hold sum of all date keys to clarify I am providing the required output in the reqArray variable below

```
reqArray = [
        {
            "channelName": "AFM",
            "21-Apr-2022": 2,
            "22-Apr-2022": 2,
            "27-Apr-2022": 1,
            "29-Apr-2022": 3,
            "19-Apr-2022": 1,
            "total":9
        },
        {
            "channelName": "Organic Others",
            "6-Apr-2022": 6,
            "27-Apr-2022": 4,
            "7-Apr-2022": 3,
            "21-Apr-2022": 1,
            "8-Apr-2022": 1
            "total": 15
        },
        {
           "channelName": "website",
            "27-Apr-2022": 1,
            "total" : 1
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code and describe the problem you encountered.

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < channelWiseSignUpInfo.length; i++) {
        const total = Object.keys(channelWiseSignUpInfo[i]).reduce((a, b) => {
            if (typeof channelWiseSignUpInfo[i][b] === 'number') {
                return a + channelWiseSignUpInfo[i][b];
            }
        });
        channelWiseSignUpInfo[i].total = total;
        console.log('Calculating total', total);
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
  function addFieldsForItem (arr = []) {
    arr.forEach(function(item) {
      let total = 0;
      Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
        if (typeof item[key] === 'number') {
          total = total + item[key]
        }
      })
      item.total = total
    })
    return arr;
  }
```

Comment: I have tried it..   
not getting desired output

Comment: ```addFieldsForItem(myObjArr);``` seems to give a result matching your reqArray's key+values. https://jsfiddle.net/2pL9f6uz/